# Flutter Firebase local change doesn't update listener stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relying on Firebase Firestore offline capabilities, so I'm not using `await` on my queries as stated on the [Access Data Offline Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline). I'm expecting that when I write something I'll get an immediate reflection on my read stream, however, I'm only getting an update when the server/remote has been updated. Basically:

1. Update something in the DB. Note, I'm not using `await`

```
 _db.doc(parentDoc).collection(DocInnerCollection).doc(childDoc).update({
        "name": value,
      });
```

2. I expect my listeners to be updated immediately. Note I've set the `includeMetadataChanges` to true as stated in the above doc.

```
_db.doc(parentDoc)
    .collection(DocInnerCollection)
    .orderBy('start_date', 'desc')
    .limitToLast(1)
    .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true)
    .map((snapshot) {
  print(snapshot.metadata.isFromCache)
});
```

However, I get no such update and instead I only get an update when the server has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requesting only one document with `.limitToLast(1)`, yet are not providing a sort order for your query. This essentially means that you'll get a random document from your collection, and the chances of that being the newly updated document are close to zero.

If you want the latest (not just last) document, you need some ordering criteria to determine what latest means. Typically you'd do this by:

1. Adding a `lastUpdated` field to your documents, and setting that to [`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp%60).
2. [Ordering your query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) on that timestamp with `orderBy('lastUpdated', 'desc')`.
3. And then limiting to the first result with `limit(1)`.

Comment: That's my bad. I'm providing sort in my code and have just forgotten to add in the example too. Apologies

Comment: Your code doesn't modify the `start_date` field. Writing just `name` doesn't change anything about the sort-order it seems.

Comment: Right, but in my case, `childDoc` is directly targetting the result I get from `limit(1)`. I expect if I modify that entry, the stream will be updated. Again, this works when the device is online, but doesn't when offline (e.g. when using cache)

Comment: In any case, I tried adding the last updated field and sorting on that, however, I'm getting the same results. It seems firebase does not fire the update given the cache is only updated but needs the server too

Comment: If that's the case, I recommend updating your question to not use a query to listen for that doc, but use ` _db.doc(parentDoc).collection(DocInnerCollection).doc(childDoc).snapshots()` to see if you can reproduce it with that too.

Comment: I can't do that. I know the `childDoc` id because of the limit query

Comment: I understand that you may need the query in your actual, but for a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it should not make a difference and could have prevented this goose chase. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯